# Strange Laravel Flash Session on Phone browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-session

I've found a very strange issue with Laravel (5.4) flash session.

Let's say I have 2 forms, signup and login. each form has laravel validation in its controller. the problem is:

1. Validation error message won't appear after redirect back (even the session is empty when I check it with $errors->any())
2. But, if I switch the redirect (login validation error redirect to signup; and signup validation error redirect to login) the error messages appeared.
3. These conditions only happened in mobile phone browser.

I've already try this to fix it with:

1. mobile phone clear history
2. change the sesson driver (cookie, database, file)

But they didn't work.

Here is my signup controller:

```
$inputs = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
        'name'              => 'required|regex:/^[A-z ]+$/',
        'email'             => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'phone'             => 'required',
        'password'          => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect('sign-up')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

And here is my login controller

```
$inputs = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: are you using laravel auth?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Laravel Auth

Comment: Then did you changed the default route and all?

Comment: No, I use Laravel standard route

Comment: but what about this route `return redirect('sign-up')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: in the signup controller, when it fails, I redirect back to sign-up, and parse the inputs and the error messages. I already tried return back() too, like one in the login controller, but the session still empty.

Comment: no what i meant to say is that the named route `sign-up` is not default it seems

Comment: and also did you tried `return back()->withErrors($validator);` only rather than with `withInput()`

Comment: my controller named RegistrationController, and in the route web.php I have Route::resource('sign-up', 'RegistrationController'); and the redirection is working properly, except that the $error is empty. and it happens only in mobile phone. on Desktop computers, the $error is working properly.